# How put values from cycle to multi array

Tags: java, arrays

I have such a cycle (it is piece of my other code):

```
for (int i = 2; i < 257; i = i * 2) {
  V -= i + 0;
  System.out.println("Suma: " +V+ " atemus: "+i);
  ///////////////////
  int X [][] = new int [8][16]; //multi array where i need to put "i" values
}
```

and how you see in code have i muti array:

```
int X [][] = new int [8][16];
```

How put values of `i` in array and print it into a screen?

ok i put my whole code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class IV_darbas {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        int r, H, R, V, x, k, z;

        Scanner ivestis = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean pabaiga = false;
        while (!pabaiga) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Si programa leis skaiciuoti turi");
            System.out.println("Jei noresi testi spausk bet kuri klavisa");
            System.out.println("Kai noresi baigti ivesk zodi: pabaiga ");

            String first = "testi";

            // Ivedi "R" reiksme
            Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ivesk reiksme: R");
            R = one.nextInt();

            // Ivedi "H" reiksme
            Scanner two = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ivesk reiksme: H");
            H = two.nextInt();

            // Ivedi "R" reiksme
            Scanner three = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ivesk reiksme: r");
            r = three.nextInt();

            V = (int) ((Math.PI * Math.pow(H, 4) * (Math.pow(R, 2)
                    + Math.pow(r, 2) + Math.pow(r, 5) * Math.pow(r, 3))) / 3);

            System.out.println("Tavo gautas turis: " + V);
            z = V * (-1);
            System.out.println("Tavo gautas turis(su priesingu zenklu):" + z);

            // Ivedamas papildomas skaicius
            Scanner four = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ivesk dar viena skaiciu: ");
            x = four.nextInt();
            k = x * z;

            // salygos if sakinys
            System.out.println("Pakeisto ir papildomo skaciaus sandauga: " + k);
            if (k > 0) {
                System.out.println("gautas skaicius " + k + " yra teigiamas");
            } else if (k < 0) {
                System.out.println("gautas skaicius " + k + " yra neigiamas");
            } else if (k == 0) {
                System.out.println("gautas skaicius " + k + " yra neutralus");

            }

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Sumavimas. Prie gauto rezultato: " + V);
            for (int i=2; i<257; i=i*2 ){
                  V += i+0;
                  System.out.println("Suma: " +V+ " pridejus: "+i);

            }



            V = (int) ((Math.PI * Math.pow(H, 4) * (Math.pow(R, 2)
                    + Math.pow(r, 2) + Math.pow(r, 5) * Math.pow(r, 3))) / 3);

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Atimtis. Prie gauto rezultato: " + V);
            for (int i=2; i<257; i=i*2 ){
                  V -= i+0;
                  System.out.println("Suma: " +V+ " atemus: "+i);
                  ///////////////////
                  int X [][] = new int [8][16];


            }


            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Ar testi? (n/y)");
            first = ivestis.next();
            if (first.equalsIgnoreCase("Pabaiga")) {
                System.out.println("Darbas baigtas!");
                break;


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The value you store in your array "X" will not persist outside your foor loop and you are creating a new instance of "X" everytime, so all your "previous" X's will go waste... and  why are you doing V-=i+0?.. What exactly do you wan to do?

Comment: Without any sample input/output, it's hard to say what you want to achieve.

Comment: Only you can tell us where you need to put `i` in `X`, but I suggest using two loops for the x and y of your matrix to build it up to simplify your code.

Comment: @TheLostMind The way it is written it will not persist from one iteration to the next ;)

Comment: You are initializing a new array `X` for every loop...

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Ya... Was editing my post when you commented.. thanks anyways.. :P

Comment: ok, added whole code, that you understand it better

Comment: There is quiz going on where you have to first translate what the program wants to understand the question and then provide correct result

Comment: Why are you doing " V -= i+0;" .. It makes no difference whatsoever.. And where do you want to use your "X".. i.e, where do you want to put your print statement in your code...

Comment: You deo realise that `Math.pow(r, 5) * Math.pow(r, 3)` is the same as `Math.pow(r, 8)` I don't remember any powers of 8 in any formula in geometry.  Can you say what this formula does and how it relates to your matrix?

Answer (score 1):

It is very unclear what you are trying to do and here is an example of what you might want to do.

```
// declared before any loop so it is in scope after the loop
int[][] values = new int[8][16];
int i = 1;
for(int x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < values[x].length; y++) {
        values[x][y] = i;
        i += 2;
    }
}
// to print the values
for(int x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < values[x].length; y++) {
        System.out.print(values[x][y] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking just how to add something to an array it goes like this:

```
X[n] = i;
```

where n is an index in the array. But as someone already said you need to declare your array outside of the loop, otherwise it won't be accessible.